# MP3 copy within an iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, mp3, mpmediapickercontroller

Is it possible to make a copy of an MP3 (or other audio) that is in my iTunes library to the *Document Directory* of an app in Swift?
I have tried through the use of `MPMediaPickerController`, but failed.

Reference: [Trying to make a file copy from MPMediaPickerController but ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987133/trying-to-make-a-file-copy-from-mpmediapickercontroller-but)

Comment: May help you....  https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/import-audio-from-ipod-music-library-swift/

Comment: Yes, that did help me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: It does not show how to to it when the format is MP3 though.